# How to auto remove torrents with moved/deleted files in rtorrent?

Tags: linux, libtorrent

In rtorrent, let's say I'm seeding a torrent and I delete its contents from my hard drive.  rtorrent eventually notices and the torrent shows "Download registered as completed, but hash check returned unfinished chunks".  Can I make rtorrent automatically remove the torrent when this happens?

Comment: this has 0 to do with programming, and would only be on topic on SuperUser or [unix.se]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manually run

> rtcontrol --from-view started is_complete=yes is_ghost=yes --delete

or put it in a cron schedule, if this is a regular thing.

See https://code.google.com/p/pyroscope/wiki/RtControlExamples#Automatic_stop_of_torrents_having_problems for more.

Comment: This put me on the right track.  I ended up using `rtcontrol is_ghost=yes --delete --yes`